# Why include SvSETMAGIC() on output variables in an XSUB?

Tags: perl, xs

Reading the [perlxs documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html), I came to the section on the `OUTPUT` keyword:

> **xsubpp** emits an automatic `SvSETMAGIC()` for all parameters in the
>   OUTPUT section of the XSUB, except RETVAL. This is the usually desired
>   behavior, as it takes care of properly invoking 'set' magic on output
>   parameters (needed for hash or array element parameters that must be
>   created if they didn't exist).

I am not sure I understand why is `set` magic is desired (and why it is not desired for `RETVAL`)? And why is `set` magic needed for hash and array element parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of Perl's data structures support magic, not just `SV`s (despite the name) and specifically for hashes and arrays this is the basis for things like the `tie` mechanism or things like `fieldhash` which implements an analogue of weak references at the level of hash entries.

Since the `OUTPUT` directive indicates which arguments would presumably be modified by the C body of the XSUB, and a variable containing set magic might be passed in, setting the value as per the typemap without invoking the set handler may result in inconsistent behaviour.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(weaken);

my $foo;
my $ref = \$foo;
weaken($ref);
```

As an example of magic, `weaken` decrements the reference count of `$foo`, and adds magic pointing back to `$ref` so that it is cleared it when `$foo` gets garbage collected.

Additionally, it also adds set magic to `$ref`, to tear down this back referencing, otherwise when `$foo` is destroyed, `$ref` would be cleared even though at this point it's no longer pointing at `$foo`.

If you use $ref as an argument, it gets aliased on the stack (which is why [`$_[0]` is assignable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION)):

```
modifies_arguments($ref);

sub modifies_arguments {
    $_[0] = "blah"; # set magic is invoked to tear down the back referencing
}
```

If `modifies_arguments` is a pure Perl it's easy to see why this is appropriate, but the same assumptions about correctness must of course hold for XSUBs, which is why `OUTPUT` is used to mark which arguments will have their value set to whatever the C level argument variable had at the end of the function body, and have set magic triggered.

This does not apply to `RETVAL`, since that is not technically an assignment, but rather pushing a new SV onto the stack, and any set magic will be handled after the function returns by the assignment op (if any).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! What about the quoted text in parenthesis: *`"needed for hash or array element parameters that must be created if they didn't exist"`*? What does this refer to? Does it mean that `set` magic is not applied to scalars or something else?

Comment: `my @array; modifies_arguments($array[42])` would only create the array element when it is actually modified, cf. autovivification. If the array is magical, then this would involve set magic on the array itself. However, this still applies to scalars, as in the `$ref` example above.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. Whenever you assign to a scalar, you need to call `SvSETMAGIC()` on it afterwards in case it has magic associated with it.

Assigning to `RETVAL` doesn't assign to a Perl variable, so calling `SvSETMAGIC(RETVAL)` (unless you've actually modified `RETVAL`) would be wrong. If the returned value is assigned to another scalar in the caller, then the assignment will call `SvGETMAGIC` on the returned value before the assignment, and `SvSETMAGIC` on the assigned variable after the assignment.